# Dependency on systemd service files

Tags: systemd

I am somewhat experienced in system d concepts namely unit files etc.
Now i have a requirement as my Unit file A should be dependent on B if some criteria is met(say some varibake value) else dependant on C unit file or service.

Is this feature available in systemd?

Comment: There is no such feature of conditional dependency in systemd unit file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your dependent services to a file and assign to an env var, for example in `/etc/foo/bar.env`

```
BAR_DEPENDENCIES=apple banana cereal
```

And then in your bar.service file,

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/foo/bar.env
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemctl start $BAR_DEPENDENCIES
ExecStart=/opt/foo/bar.exe
```

This will start `apple`, `banana` and `cereal` services. You can modify the `/etc/foo/bar.env` file programmatically before starting the `bar` service to add or remove services.

I've also used a help service to write the environment file, and specified that help service as `Requires=` in the main service, so that it runs before the main service.